# When is the Google Cloud SQL API required? Some connections fail, others succeed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

My Google App Engine app fails to connect to my Google Cloud SQL instance with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The Google Cloud SQL API is not enabled for project [{project-id}]. Please use the Google Developers Console to enable it: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview?project={project-id}
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.obtainInstanceMetadata(SslSocketFactory.java:389) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.fetchInstanceSslInfo(SslSocketFactory.java:284) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstanceSslInfo(SslSocketFactory.java:264) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.createAndConfigureSocket(SslSocketFactory.java:183) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:152) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48) ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar!/:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar!/:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar!/:5.1.44]
```

That's strange, because I thought the API was enabled. The APIs dashboard has an entry for Google Cloud SQL with no activity and a "disable" button.

The app uses the Cloud SQL Socket Factory:

```
jdbc:mysql://google/{database}?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance={instance connection name copied from console}&useSSL=false
```

When the app runs locally it connects to and updates the remote Cloud SQL instance.

The Cloud SQL instance is 2nd generation, HA, and requires SSL. All of the "gcloud sql" commands I've tried succeeded. I can interact with the database using command line tools and a local Cloud SQL Proxy.

Before I click the "Enable" button on the API I'd like to understand why the API already appears in the API dashboard (with an option to disable), and why only Cloud SQL Socket Factory connections from a Google App Engine instance fail.

Comment: Is your app engine app in the same project as your Cloud SQL instance? There's also no need to use Cloud SQL Socket Factory if you're using App Engine Standard.

Comment: The App Engine App and Cloud SQL instance are in the same project. The app uses the flexible environment and java8 runtime.

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message? There are multiple "SQL" APIs and you may have been looking at a different one. Clicking the link in the error message guarantees you'll go to the right one.

Comment: Yes, I followed the link in the error message when I found it this morning. That presented the "Enable" button I was reluctant to click. I just clicked it. Now the API dashboard has two "API" entries with "Google Cloud SQL" in the name: "Google Cloud SQL" and "Google Cloud SQL API". My app connects to and updates the database. I still don't understand why the app doesn't need the "Google Cloud SQL API" API to connect when running locally. Maybe a difference between my credentials and VM credentials. Thanks for looking in to this.